# how to verify and correct if street deleted during update to OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap

I downloaded the map data from Open Street Map and also overpass-api.de (one of the alternative download sources) for a small section of Toronto, and one major road is missing, even though that same road is visible in the map when viewed on Open Street Map. That area of Toronto was recently updated on Open Street Map (as explained at the bottom of this post) so I'm guessing the street got accidentally deleted but I'm not sure how to verify this.

This is a small part of the map https://www.openstreetmap.org/export#map=15/43.6859/-79.4063

The street that's missing in the data download is St. Clair West (and also St. Clair), but it's visible on the map when viewed on OSM.

In the xml format, the streets in the map are represented as way(s) and the name of the street is represented as a key value inside the way -> tag namespace. For example, this is a way for Yonge Street with some of the data (data irrelevant for this question) stripped out

`<way id="45760140" version="8" timestamp="2013-05-30T16:15:30Z" changeset="16353889" uid="1679" user="andrewpmk"> 
    <tag k="name" v="Yonge Street"/> 
  </way>`

In the data for the map I linked to, I can find a way for every street except St. Clair West and St. Clair but they are major streets and, as mentioned are visible in the map viewed on Open Street Map.I downloaded the data several times.

Question: Is it possible the map data was updated and somehow that street got left out because it was obviously there at one time? Is there a way to access an old version of the data to see if that's what happened?

I know that the data for the area was updated fairly recently because a racket club on that street burnt down, which is noted in the Open Street Data below. This is why I'm guessing the whole street got somehow deleted during the update. I'm fairly new to Open Street Map and not sure if there's an older copy of the data.

```
  <way id="115222336" version="5" timestamp="2017-02-15T01:00:33Z" changeset="46094294" uid="1679" user="andrewpmk">
    <nd ref="800029023"/>
    <nd ref="800029006"/>
    <nd ref="800029008"/>
    <nd ref="800029002"/>
    <nd ref="800029005"/>
    <nd ref="800028991"/>
    <nd ref="800029000"/>
    <nd ref="800029038"/>
    <nd ref="800029042"/>
    <nd ref="800029018"/>
    <nd ref="800029023"/>
    <tag k="addr:city" v="Toronto"/>
    <tag k="addr:country" v="CA"/>
    <tag k="addr:housenumber" v="25"/>
    <tag k="addr:province" v="ON"/>
    <tag k="addr:street" v="Saint Clair Avenue West"/>
    <tag k="landuse" v="brownfield"/>
    <tag k="name" v="The Badminton and Racquet Club of Toronto (burnt down February 14, 2017)"/>
    <tag k="shop" v="vacant"/>
  </way>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use the openstreetmap.org Query Tool (the "?" question mark icon on the right) and point to any location on the map to request further details about a particular object.

If you downloadeded data from overpass-api.de and used some specific filter rules (like `way[highway=residential]`), that may also cause some streets to be missing in your query result, if they use different tags such as `highway=secondary`.

As it turns out, the street name appears to be "Saint Clair Avenue West" rather than "St. Clair West", and it's been this way for at least 3 years now, see http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/32597026 an an example.

Comment: Hi,  As I mentioned, the street is visible viewing on the site, but not in the data download, and I looked for both St. Clair West and St. Clair Avenue West. I downloaded the data from overpass and also from osm and it's not in either (that I can see) and I didn't apply secondary filters. I just downloaded the data again from OSM and uploaded it to my dropbox if you care to have a look https://www.dropbox.com/home/public?preview=map-yonge-st-clair.osm

Comment: oops, I see what you mean. It is "Saint Clair". I apologize and will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to mmd's suggestion you can also just open your favorite OSM editor (e.g. [iD](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/ID) or [JOSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM)) and take a look at the data. This works a lot better than looking at raw XML.